# How to execute tests (multiple feature files) across environments in parallel in Karate DSL

Tags: karate

How to execute tests(feature files) across multiple environments in parallel using Karate DSL

I have two feature files which I need to execute in parallel across the different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second feature file, and call the feature you want in 2 scenarios, but passing different arguments.

You can even use a `Scenario Outline`, for an example see this:

```
Scenario Outline:
  * call read('some.feature') <config>

Examples:
    | config |
    | { type: 'chrome' } | 
    | { type: 'chromedriver' } |
    | { type: 'geckodriver' } |
```